# Running a python program with cron, Docker and Supervisor

Tags: python, docker, cron, supervisord

When I run build the container with the CMD as `CMD /usr/bin/python3 /app/test.py`  everything runs fine and I see an output, but when I run the CMD as `CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]` which runs supervisor and cron, I see not output.  It seems like the python file is not running, or i'm not properly setup to see logging.

How can I ensure the python file is running and how can I see the output?

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils -y cron -y liblapack3 -y build-essential \
                    -y python3-dev -y python3-setuptools -y python3-numpy \
                    -y python3-scipy -y python3-pip -y libatlas-dev \
                    -y supervisor


COPY . /app

# install requirements (early and on their own to leverage caching)
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt

# make script executable
RUN chmod +x /app/test.py

# do cron stuff
COPY ./crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log


COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
CMD /usr/bin/python3 /app/test.py
```

supervisord.conf is:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel=debug

[program:cron]
command = cron -f -L 15
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

crontab is:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/python3 /app/test.py
* * * * * root echo "hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

and test.py is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging

from lib.rig import settings

#set logging level to INFO
logging.getLogger().setLevel(settings.get('logging_level'))

logging.info('LOLOLOL')
print('this is a print')
```

Comment: I dont see PATH in `crontab` that can cause why python program is not executed - if you dont have it there just add something like
 `SHELL=/bin/sh
   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` - check [34.1.1. Configuring Cron Tasks](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-autotasks.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `PATH` environment variable declaration, which is causing your Python app to not run. Editing your Dockerfile to the following should fix the issue for you:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# This is the line that matters ^^

RUN apt-get update
...
```

See more on the `ENV` variable [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env).